# My selenium script is running fine in eclipse but not in jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have created script using TestNG annotation and maven. It runs expected in Eclipse, I also tried to run testng.xml file which looks good. and then I configured Jenkins but now Its not running. Jenkins giving error  as below :  (FYI : I have successful built in Jenkins previously , how this could broken in one day ???)

Starting ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69 (3c16f8a135abc0d4da2dff33804db79b849a7c38) on port 48847
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Tests run: 7, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 6, Time elapsed: 4.774 sec <<< **FAILURE! - in TestSuite
launchBrowser(com.pages.VisibilityAnnotationDemo)  Time elapsed: 4.208 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed**
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
(Driver info: chromedriver=72.0.3626.69 (3c16f8a135abc0d4da2dff33804db79b849a7c38),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19042 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 872 milliseconds

> I added below Jenkins config Root POM =
> C:\Users....\workspace\VRsessions\pom.xml
> Goals and options = clean install

The code I am try to run , Its script to do UI validation.

```
**public String baseUrl = " URL OF PAGE";
String driverPath = "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe";
public WebDriver driver;
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

@BeforeTest
public void launchBrowser() throws InterruptedException {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(baseUrl);
                                                                                        
}**
```

Comment: Are you running in `headless` mode? Can you please share the code you are running to see this error?

Comment: added in description. thanks for looking into

Answer (score 0):

Tests on chrome, as far as I know, must be in `headless` mode to run on Jenkins. You'll need to set chrome options like this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

...

ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: unfortunately no luck with that. I have also tried to use the latest version of chrome but still not working.

Comment: This issue is resolved now. It was chrome driver issue so I installed latest chrome and chrome driver and copy it to the location given in the log. I re-run the build and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**To fix this:**
Add the the `--disable-dev-shm-usage, --headless, --no-sandbox` command line option to Chrome. And you also need to pass the `ChromeOptions` object to `new ChromeDriver(options);`

**Code:**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get(baseUrl);
```